# Ignoring characters in search with ack

Tags: php, regex, ack

I am using ack to search for instances of the PHP function "split(" that has now been deprecated. Unfortunately, it is bringing up instances of preg_split (which is still valid), how can I ignore these results, whilst still searching for "split("?

```
ack --type=php split\\\(
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ack --type=php '[^_]split\('
```

Since `preg_split()` has an underscore before the split, just use a negated match for the underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Well a solution could be to do more search/replace not for split but split preceded by:

- ;
- space
- tab

Comment: It's explicitly preg_split I want to ignore

Answer (score 0):

One brute-force way would be to use the `-w` flag to only see `split` as a word.

```
ack -w split
```

That will still give you hits on "split" that aren't actually function calls if you have any.  But sometimes the low-tech way is easiest.